# What will be the part of speech when you combine a Verb and a Noun?

Tags: verbs, nouns, parts-of-speech

I have Verb **Cancel** and a Noun **Download** what will be it's part of speech when i combine both of those words.

Asking from a programmer perspective, my peer is saying that you are not allowed to use Verbs as component `<CancelDownload/>` name. But, is **CancelDowload** a verb, or does it belong to any part of speech?
[image: Download]
[image: Cancel]
[image: CancelDownload]

My sincere apologies if this question is too basic or it doesn't match the required threshold to be a good question.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some word types in English can be combined to make new words. NounA + nounB in particular is a very common combination, like in "threshold" where "thresh" and "hold" are combined to make a new word. When you do this, the new word becomes a nounB, modified by the meaning of nounA.

You can also **combine verbX + nounY**. This **results in a noun** that roughly means *a Y for Xing*. Examples are "dance hall" or "jam session", which mean "a hall for dancing" and "a session for jamming".

This means a "CancelDownload" would be "a download for cancelling (something)". Since your object name almost certainly doesn't have this function, it doesn't make any sense to follow the rules of English here to determine its part of speech.

Comment: I don't think this is a useful answer.  The compounds "dance hall" and "jam session" are noun+noun (a hall for holding a dance, a jam which takes place for a certain session) The relationship between "cancel" and "download" is verb+object, and the combination isn't a word.  "a cancel download" isn't a download for cancelling, it isn't a word.  I think this answer confuses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "part of speech".  It is a combination of a verb and its object.  It is a phrase of two words.

The correct spelling is "cancel download".  It is incorrect to omit the space.

If `CancelDownload` is an identifier in a computer language, that is fine, but you are not writing English. You are writing a computer language, which has its own grammar. So you can't ask what part of English speech it is.  In the computer language, its part might be "variable name" or "object identifier".

Comment: Yes, its incorrect to omit space i agree, but while writing `code` in a verbose manner, i hope we can make an exception to remove spaces and join words.

Comment: Of course you can. But what you are writing is not English: it is in whatever programming language you are using, which has its own grammar. "Part of speech" does not apply.